# weird situation for nanomsg and linux

Tags: linux, nanomsg

It's very strange.
I write a message distribute server upon nanomsg.
But after some time,when i restart the server, i failed because the listening port has been used.
Here is the situation:

```
[root@vsmHost12 src]# lsof -n -i:3333
COMMAND PID  USER FD TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
hsmcs 105013 root **20u** IPv4 **24845821** 0t0 TCP :dec-notes (LISTEN)
hsmcs 105013 root 66u IPv4 25366582 0t0 TCP 192.168.167.1:dec-notes->192.168.167.1:47826 (ESTABLISHED)
java 111946 root **20u** IPv4 **24845821** 0t0 TCP *:dec-notes (LISTEN)
java 111946 root 34u IPv6 25366581 0t0 TCP 192.168.167.1:47826->192.168.167.1:dec-notes (ESTABLISHED)
```

It's not because of the java, some other daemon may also have the problem.
Look at the FD number and DEVICE number, it's the SAME!
Can anyone explain it ?